# QuantLib - Calibrating Hull White one-factor on negative interest rates

Tags: quantlib, hullwhite, short-rate, negative

I have been working with the QuantLib Python package for some days now. Currently, I am working on calibrating a Hull White one-factor model for short rates. I am calibrating the model on the yield-curve and on swaption volatilities.

Given the current market circumstances, a large part of the yield curve is negative. This causes some issues with calibrating the Hull White one-factor model since the lognormal distribution cannot be negative. After some searching I found the possibility of specifying a shift. In the code below my SwaptionHelper initialization is shown including the shift.

Please note I am currently using a yield curve, however, when using a flatforward of -0.00478 I get similar results.

However, using the shift results in unrealistic output for a (a=0.0000389, sigma=0.0222).

I have been searching a lot for an answer, but cannot find decent information for situations with a negative rate. If anyone would be able to explain the usage of a shift or do a quick check on my code to see if anything is wrong would be so helpful.

```
helper = ql.SwaptionHelper(
        ql.Period(int(maturity), ql.Years),
        ql.Period(int(tenor), ql.Years),
        volatility,
        index,
        fixedLegTenor,
        fixedLegDayCounter,
        floatingLegDayCounter,
        term_structure,
        ql.BlackCalibrationHelper.RelativePriceError,
        ql.nullDouble(),
        1.0,
        ql.ShiftedLognormal,
        0.05 #shift to make rates non-negative
    )
```

Full code:

```
import csv
from QuantLib.QuantLib import SwaptionHelper
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import QuantLib as ql

def load_csv_input():
    zero_curve = pd.read_csv('ZeroCurve.csv', delimiter=';')
    dates = []
    rates = []

    for i in range(0,len(zero_curve)):
        rates.append(float(zero_curve['Rate'][i]))
        dates.append(ql.Date(int(zero_curve['Mat_Day'][i]),int(zero_curve['Mat_Month'][i]),int(zero_curve['Mat_Year'][i])))

    return dates, rates

# Read the swaption volatilities from the csv file.
swaption_vols = pd.read_csv('SwaptionVol.csv', delimiter=';', index_col=0)
dates, rates = load_csv_input()

curve = ql.ZeroCurve(dates, rates, ql.Actual365Fixed())
term_structure = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(curve)

model = ql.HullWhite(term_structure)
#engine = ql.TreeSwaptionEngine(model, 25)
engine = ql.JamshidianSwaptionEngine(model)
#engine = ql.G2SwaptionEngine(model, 10, 400)

index = ql.Euribor1Y(term_structure)
fixedLegTenor = ql.Period('1Y')
fixedLegDayCounter = ql.Actual360()
floatingLegDayCounter = ql.Actual360()

swaptions = []
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(1, 10, 2020)
for maturity in swaption_vols.index:
    for tenor in swaption_vols.columns:
        volatility = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(swaption_vols.at[maturity,tenor]))
        helper = ql.SwaptionHelper(
            ql.Period(int(maturity), ql.Years),
            ql.Period(int(tenor), ql.Years),
            volatility,
            index,
            fixedLegTenor,
            fixedLegDayCounter,
            floatingLegDayCounter,
            term_structure,
            ql.BlackCalibrationHelper.RelativePriceError,
            ql.nullDouble(),
            1.0,
            ql.ShiftedLognormal,
            0.2 #shift to make rates non-negative
        )
        helper.setPricingEngine(engine)
        swaptions.append(helper)

optimization_method = ql.LevenbergMarquardt(1.0e-8,1.0e-8,1.0e-8)
end_criteria = ql.EndCriteria(500000, 1000, 1e-6, 1e-8, 1e-8)
model.calibrate(swaptions, optimization_method, end_criteria)
params = model.params()
print(params)
```

**Update**

I have changed the volatility type from lognormal to normal, since the data contains normal volatilities. So this should be able to work with the negative values.

Now I am running into an issue where the calibration only works if I use a small selection of volatilities. My complete volatility matrix is 10x10 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, and 30Y maturity and tenors). However, if I use more than the first 5x5 I get a "root not bracketed" error.

Comment: I do not understand your remark "since the lognormal distribution cannot be negative." The short rate in the HW model is normal and can be negative. Lognormal are bond prices and these are positive?

Comment: You're right, the HW model is indeed normal. However, as far as I know, the calculations for the swaptions include a lognormal distribution.

Comment: I suppose I'll first further check the plausibility of the calculated Hull White parameters by constructing the implied volatility surface

Comment: @Michielap perhaps you meant that your market swaption vols are obtained with Black's formula, i.e. the data in `SwaptionVol.csv` is lognormal. Is that the case? Maybe it helps also if you could share the data.

Comment: I assumed that they were lognormal. However, I reached out to the provider of the data and apparently they are actually normal. So I am going to look into that first to see if that will change my results. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: Re “root not bracketed”: are the rates in natural units or in bps or in %? For QL you need to scale those to to nats

Comment: I thought the volatilities were given in percentages. However, in the thread below David mentioned that it likely are bps, otherwise the volatilities would be to high. I divided the values by a 100 and am now getting results. What do you mean by scaling to nats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building a SwaptionHelper, you have to tell QuantLib what kind of volatility you are inputting. There are three options: Black Vol, Shifted Black Vol and Normal Vol.

Since you don't have black vol for most of the swaption surface (EUR) because of the negative forwards, you can either use shifted Black Vol or Normal Vol.

In the example you are using shifted black vol but you have a shift of 20%! Your shifted vols should have a respective shift value but I doubt it is 20%. ICAP for example quotes shifted black vols with a shift of 2% for EUR rates.

Without doing any code, I would guess if you correct your shift to the appropriate value you'll get better results. You can compare the model values with the market values for your helpers.

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for your help. I actually managed to find that my data consists of normal volatilities. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that should mean that I can remove the shift since normal can handle negative values. I updated my script to show the differences between model and market values.

Comment: Correct, just use ql.Normal instead of ql.ShiftedLognormal as the volatity type and don't input any shift...

Comment: Thanks David! I just wrote a brief update on my question. I keep getting a "root not bracketed" error when using the full (10x10) volatility surface. Only for smaller (5x5) surfaces the calibration yields a result.

Comment: Are you inputting the normal vol correctly? for example a normal vol of 34 refers to 34 basis points which would be inputed as 34 / 10000

Comment: I have the volatility as percentages, so for maturity and tenor of 1 year it is 0.1816. I use those directly as input for the swaptionhelper.

Comment: That would be 18% which is way too much for normal vol. 1y1y normal vol in eur would be around 18/19 bps which would be inputted as 0.0018, so I believe you will have to divide your vols by 100

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just updated my script to divide all volatilties by 100 and I am no longer getting the error. output now: a=0.00011, sigma=0.0043. a still seems a bit small at 0.00011 but perhaps that it is caused by the current market.